# LatLng gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, on-location-changed

I am working with google maps on android studio. The problem is when i access DriverLatLng[image: LatLng object]outside onLocationChanged it gives me null pointer exception.
My onLocationChanged method is as follows :-

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LastLocation = location;
    double lat = LastLocation.getLatitude();
    double lon = LastLocation.getLongitude();
    DriverLatLng = new LatLng(lat,lon);
    Log.v("data", DriverLatLng.toString());
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(DriverLatLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
}
```

Now when i use DriverLatLng anywhere else i get

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng.toString()' on a null object reference
> ```

Comment: As @Madonabulia said,it could be caused before initializing driverLatlng

Comment: I have set the interval at 1 second, so it cannot be null at any given moment while the app is running. I am running it on real device

Comment: Added relevant tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `location`, `lat` and `lon` aren't null before you use `DriverLatLng`.

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LastLocation = location;
    double lat = LastLocation.getLatitude();
    double lon = LastLocation.getLongitude();
    if(lat == null || lon == null){
       Log.v("nulls", "lat and/or lon are null");
    } else{
       DriverLatLng = new LatLng(lat,lon);
       Log.v("data", DriverLatLng.toString());
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(DriverLatLng));
       mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }
}
```

Also, note that GoogleApiClient is deprecated. You need to use [GoogleApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApi). Check out [this post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/moving-past-googleapiclient_21.html).

Hope this helps!